# How can I do this 5^623 ≡ x mod 41

Tags: discrete-mathematics

how can I do this I know  Euler-Ferman thesis  5^623 ≡ x mod 41, 5φ(41)≡ 1 (mod 41)
but I can't calculate this (5^40)^15 * 5^23 ≡ x mod(41)

Comment: But $5^{40}\equiv1\pmod{41}$. To get $5^{23}$ you can use repeated squaring for example.

Comment: I  try this but  I can't know I can add remainder ?

Comment: I calculate this 5^5 * 5^5 *5^5* 5^5 ≡ 9 mod(41)  5^3 ≡ 2 (mod 41)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$5^{20} \equiv 1 \mod 41$ so $5^{623}=5^{31 \times 20}5^3 \equiv (1)^{20}(125) \mod 41 \equiv 2 \mod 41$.

Or easier:

$5^{10} \equiv -1 \mod 41$ so $5^{623} = 5^{62\times 10}5^3=(-1)^{62}(125) \equiv 2 \mod 41$.

Comment: How do you know 5^20 ≡ 1 mod 41?

Comment: @shipman102 I added an easier method for knowing $5^{10} \equiv -1 \mod 41$.

Comment: @helynr thank you  I understand how to do and I can do my version with a smaller  number  :)